# Tuple size default constructor and its conversion to std::size_t

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

In the code below I am wondering how exactly `std::tuple_size<T>{}` and `std::tuple_size<T>()` return the size of the tuple. When looking at the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_size) for using this call, it seems that I should either have to use the `() operator` or the static `::value` member variable in order to get the tuple size. However, when running this code it compiles and produces the correct output, how is `tuple_size` returning the value from the constructor?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <class T>
void test(T)
{
    //std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>{}>{} Seen used like this spurned my ?
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<T>{} << '\n';
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<T>() << '\n';
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<T>()() << '\n';
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<T>::value << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    test(std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3.14));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_size

Says:

> Member constants
>
> value
>
> [static]
>
> sizeof...(Types)  (public static member constant)
>
> Member functions
>
> operator std::size_t
>
> converts the object to std::size_t, returns value  (public member
>   function)
>
> operator()
>
> (C++14)
>
> returns value  (public member function)

So no wonder.
1st & 2nd form use conversion operator.
3rd form explicitly calls function call operator.
4th form uses static member.
This is an exceptionally convenient std utility. No other std tool has as many convenience functions.